# HorizontalScrollView is hard to scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling

I have a `HorizontalScrollView`. The `HorizontalScrollView` is working fine but there is a problem with the sliding. The slide is working fine (at least at exact same position) but if the user keeps sliding, the user may move his hand to up or down and then the sliding stop.
My question is how to keep it sliding even if the user got a mistake and moved his hand in the whole screen? Keep in mind the user didn't release his touch.
Here is my related code to `XML`

```
....

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizantal_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/services_linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


            </HorizontalScrollView>
....
```